# How can I test passing data across graphs and routes with jetpack compose navigation?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation

Here's my code

```kotlin
class NavigationTest {
    @get:Rule(order = 0)
    val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @get:Rule(order = 1)
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    lateinit var navController: TestNavHostController

    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialNavigationApi::class)
    @Before
    fun setupAppNavHost() {
        hiltRule.inject()

        composeTestRule.setContent {
            navController = TestNavHostController(LocalContext.current)
            navController.navigatorProvider.addNavigator(ComposeNavigator())
            MainNavHost(navController = navController) // This part is the problem.
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun appNavHost_verifyStartDestination() {
        composeTestRule
            .onNodeWithContentDescription("Start Screen")
            .assertIsDisplayed()
    }
}
```

There are two parts that are different from official doc - hilt and MainNavHost.

MainNavHost looks like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MainNavHost(
    onBackClick: () -> Unit,
    appState: AppState,
    deviceDisplayState: DeviceDisplayState,
    bottomSheetNavigator: BottomSheetNavigator,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
    startDestination: String = entryGraphRoutePattern
) {
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        bottomSheetNavigator,
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 30.dp, topEnd = 30.dp)
    ) {
        AnimatedNavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = startDestination,
            enterTransition = { EnterTransition.None },
            exitTransition = { ExitTransition.None },
            modifier = modifier
        ) {
           ...
      }
    )
}
```

So, to create MainNavHost(), I need these params.

```kotlin
onBackClick: () -> Unit,
appState: AppState,
deviceDisplayState: DeviceDisplayState,
bottomSheetNavigator: BottomSheetNavigator,
modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
startDestination: String = entryGraphRoutePattern
```

And I have no idea how to create them.
For AppState. It looks like this:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialNavigationApi::class)
@Stable
class AppState constructor(
    val bottomSheetNavigator: BottomSheetNavigator,
    val navController: NavHostController,
    val webViewState: WebViewState,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    networkMonitor: NetworkMonitor
) {
   ...
}
```

So, Even though I try to create AppState, I have no idea how to create the params in Test Code.

1. networkMonitor is injected in Activity

```kotlin
    @Inject
    lateinit var networkMonitor: NetworkMonitor
```

2. deviceDisplayState looks like this

```kotlin
// rememberDeviceDisplayState is just remember 'DeviceDisplayState(displays, presentationHandler, forceSplit)'
// And displayManager is 'displayManager = getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE) as DisplayManager'
val deviceDisplayState = rememberDeviceDisplayState(
                displays = displayManager?.displays,
                presentationHandler = this,
                forceSplit = true
               )
```

and so on.

And I'd like to test the deep links(I mean routes and graphs)

So, I'd like to do this.

1. start with aScreen.
2. navigate to `bScreen?param1=abc`.
3. (maybe check bScreen's viewModel and check if it has abc in param1 variable.)
4. navigate to `cScreen?paramX=0&paramY=abc`
   and so on.

How can I achieve this test?